# Swift 1.2 - Bridging-Header file not found message in Xcode 6.3.2 and Xcode 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Building an app on Xcode 6.3.2, now updated to Xcode 4 but it's the same.
I need to import Facebook sdks and Parse sdks

Xcode tells me that the Bridging-Header.h file is not found. I made it this way:

- highlighted in the project navigator the Supporting Files group
- file/newFile/ios file/ header File

(I tried both checking and unchecking "targets")

- named projectName-Bridging-Header.h
- building Settings, select "targets" / objective -c bridging-header = "projectName/projectName-Bridging-Header.h"

[image]

build
error

Comment: did you set it in build settings->swift compiler - code generation area?

Comment: yes, I updated with an image, to be sure

Answer (score 0):

According the build settings the header is expected to be in the subfolder `Lug1` of the project folder. This specifies the physical folder on disk not any virtual folder in the side bar

If the name of the project is Lug1 the naming of the header is correct

Comment: Yes, Lug1 is The name of The project

Comment: then check the path on disk

Comment: is on Lug1/Lug1/ should be the right one, the matter is that if I create a new app, I got the same problem

Comment: try to create a new Swift project and drag any Objective-C header file (not framework) into the side bar. Xcode will ask you to create an bridging header automatically

Comment: you mean file/newFile/ios source/ obj-c file?

Comment: I meant dragging an exiting file, but creating a new one is supposed to work too

Comment: dummy app :  creates the file, no problem, old app, got problem. would you like to see my files? maybe via dropbox

Comment: the project is a bit messed up. It's how I suspected. The bridging header is physically in [projectfolder]/Lug1-Bridging-Header but specified in Build settings [projectfolder]//Lug1/Lug1-Bridging-Header. I recommend to let Xcode always create the header.

Comment: so, you say that from now on, for creating a Bridging-Header I should create a dummy obj-c file, erase it and keep the bridging header? now, could you tell me how should it be the "Right" ensemble of settings? maybe with a screenshot, I'm not sure what I should have in Build settings. thanks in advance

Comment: yes, this is the safest way, because Xcode does everything for you including the proper build settings

Comment: I see, but if I correct the path in [projectfolder]/Lug1-Bridging-Header error persists.